# How random is the digits of $\pi$?

Tags: random, pi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Distribution of the digits of Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51829/distribution-of-the-digits-of-pi)

If we plot the digits of $\pi$

$3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058\cdots$

versus the indices

$((1, 3), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 1), \cdots)$

How to quantify the randomness of the resultant curve?

The first part of the curve looks like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=list+plot+%7B1%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C9%2C2%2C6%2C5%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C9%2C7%2C9%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C8%2C4%2C6%2C2%2C6%2C4%2C3%2C3%2C8%2C3%2C2%2C7%2C9%7D) .

#### Re: @Henning Makholm

Rephrasing the question, suppose the [curve](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=list+plot+%7B1%2C4%2C1%2C5%2C9%2C2%2C6%2C5%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C9%2C7%2C9%2C3%2C2%2C3%2C8%2C4%2C6%2C2%2C6%2C4%2C3%2C3%2C8%2C3%2C2%2C7%2C9%7D) happens to be a sample function of a random process, how to give the distribution of that random process?

Comment: In one quite important sense they are _not random at all_, because they are the one and only sequence that are _the decimal digits of $\pi$_. That's an extremely specific property.

Comment: You might like to take a look at [Normal Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).

Comment: There are lots of ways to try to quantify randomness. Which are appropriate will depend on what you intend to do with the result.

Answer (score 4):

Histogram of the first 10000 digits

[image: Digits of Pi]

Covariance of the first 10000 consecutive digits: -0.09 (negligible)

---

Mathematica code used:

Histogram:

```
Histogram[RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000][[1]], 10]
```

Covariance: (I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this)

```
N[Covariance[RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000][[1]][[Range[1, 9999]]], 
   RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000][[1]][[Range[2, 10000]]]]]
```

Comment: @PeterSheldrick: mathematica: Histogram[RealDigits[Pi, 10, 10000][[1]], 10]

Comment: If any of you guys have more requests, I'll be happy to compute/plot more data.