# how many $1$s in the first n digits of $\pi$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, soft-question

how many $1$s are there in the first n digits of $\pi$? Any good approximation of its distribution? How about the place of the $n$th $1$? Are these two questions related?

Comment: I think  about $[n/10],$  no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is not known, but it is conjectured that $\pi$ is [simply normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_normal_number) in base $10$, and from that you would expect one tenth of the digits to be $1$s, and the $n$-th $1$ to be found near digit number $10n$, for huge values of $n$, in some sense.

Answer (score 4):

See also OEIS sequence [A037000](http://oeis.org/A037000)

Comment: Thanks, very interesting link

Answer (score 3):

There is no known answer to this question.

Comment: The exact number, as a function of $n$ is not known. There are partial answers on the question of the distribution of digits.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is not even known if there are infinitely many $1$s or not.

Comment: (To comment) What partial answers are there?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51829/distribution-of-the-digits-of-pi

Answer (score 3):

Actually, *yes*, Kavim, since $\pi$ is suspected (though not yet *proven*) to be a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). As *n* grows *large*, the ratio is *approximately* $\dfrac1{10}$ for each digit. All computations done so far, even up to over a trillion digits, confirm this [conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjecture).

Comment: the ratio is >> the ratio would be.