# Is this a non empty perfect set with no rational numbers?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, number-theory

Let $A$ be the Cantor set and   $B = \pi\, (-A \cup A)$.

Is B a perfect set with no rational numbers?

Comment: Oops, sorry! I misread the question.

Comment: Is $B=\pi(-A\cup A)$? You know $A$ contains $0$, right?

Comment: I edited the question to use LaTeX.  Please let me know if I have misrepresented your question inadvertently.

Comment: If you just wanted to construct *some* such set, see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1064/

Answer (score 1):

As Andres Caicedo pointed out, $B$ contains $0$.

It is reasonable to ask whether $B$ contains a *nonzero* rational number. This is equivalent to asking whether $A$ contains a rational multiple of $\pi$ (other than $0$).

If the answer is affirmative, then the base $3$ expansion of $\pi$ has a (complicated) infinite pattern in its digits. It is generally believed that the digits of $\pi$, in any number base, do not exhibit any infinite pattern. However, for all we know at present, the base 3 expansion of $\pi$ could have finitely many $1$s.  (See [Distribution of the digits of Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51829/) and links there.)
So, the answer to your question (with excluded $0$) is: nobody knows.