# Is this known about $\pi$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, pi, conjectures

> Suppose that we travel along the digits of $\pi$ and when we arrive at $2$ or $3$ or $4$ or $5$ or $6$ or $7$ or $8$ or $9$ we replace those digits with the number $1$ and when we arrive at $1$ or $0$ we leave them unchanged. When we do this with all the digits will resulting number be irrational?

Since this looks quite hard you can, if you want, assume that $\pi$ is normal in order to prove this. But I do not know is normality enough?

(The statement that we can suppose that $\pi$ is normal was not in the original version of the question.)

Comment: A random sequence of $0, 1$ will make an irrational number. It's unlikely that $\pi$ has some property that avoids this.

Comment: I've never heard of anyone investigating this property personally, however it is widely expected (*but not proven*) that $\pi$ is a normal number, which should imply things about lengths of sequences of zeroes in its digits which should in turn imply the irrationality of the number you describe.

Comment: Not much is known about the decimals of pi, and I suspect this would be an open problem as well.

Comment: It's unknown if the digits of $\pi$ are uniformly distributed: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51829/distribution-of-the-digits-of-pi

Comment: I would describe it as something of a miracle that we are able to prove that $\pi$ is irrational, because even that is very difficult for most numbers.

Comment: @Arthur $\pi$ was proven to be irrational [long ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational).

Comment: @Eff I'm not saying it's difficult in the case of $\pi$. I'm saying it's impossible for most real numbers, and we were lucky with $\pi$.

Comment: @Eff ... which doesn't contradict Arhur. Miracles have the general tendency to have happened long ago ...

Comment: @Arthur Ah, sorry. I read it as "[...] of a miracle **if** we are able to prove that $\pi$ is irrational".

Comment: So the question is, whether the zeros of $\pi$ appear periodically ...

Comment: @projectilemotion I doubt we will ever know whether $\pi^e$ is irrational, for instance. Or, at the very least, it is a very long time into the future.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen comparing to the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$, it was pretty recent ...

Comment: I believe it is not even known if there are infinitely many digits that are $0$. Clearly, if there were only finitely many digits $0$, it would be rational.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265310/if-i-exchange-infinitely-many-digits-of-pi-and-e-are-the-two-resulting-num

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a question.

> In a normal number, can the positions of the $0$s in the decimal be eventually periodic?

Answer: NO.  In a normal number there are arbitrarily long strings of $7$s.  (And also infinitely many $0$s.)

Comment: My oh my, i just destroyed the question with the statement that we can assume normality.

Comment: @BehindEnemyLines  Also, normality is too strong; e.g., it's enough to assume $\pi$ is [disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence).