# The Distribution of Pi’s Binary Digits

Tags: pi

So one night, I got bored, so, as you do, I made a depressingly inefficient python formula to calculate the density of the digits in a text file with a billion digits of pi in it. As I expected, it came out to roughly 10% per digit, and the precision increased proportionately to the number of digits I put in (so a billion digits was around a thousand times closer than a million was). Is there a way to prove this distribution approaches equality?

Comment: Did you find anything with Google?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51829/distribution-of-the-digits-of-pi

Comment: [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23547/does-pi-contain-1000-consecutive-zeroes-in-base-10/23551#23551) on MathOverflow seems to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Your title says binary digits but your body says roughly 10% per digit !?

Comment: If we assume that the distribution is like that of random digits, we will observe that the ratio gets closer and closer to $1/10$. The awfully many digits that have been calculated support this assumption, but noone knows whether this goes on forever. It is conjectured that $\pi$ is normal (meaning that every finite digit string occurs in the expected frequency if we look at more and more digits). But noone can rule out that eventually only two distinct digits occur, something like $01100110101110001...$